# What is the usage of MPI in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, mpi

I'm trying to find the usage of mpi4py for multiprocessing in python3. In docs i read bout ranks and their usage, and how to transfer data from a rank to another, but I could not understand how to implement it, suppose I have function that i want to run on one processor, so should I write that function under if rank == 0, and for another function if rank == 1 ..., The syntax here is confusing me. Is it like spawning process1 = multiprocessing.Process()

Answer (score 0):

MPI4PY provides bindings of the Message Passing Interface (MPI) standard for the Python and allows any Python program to exploit multiple processors.

It supports communications of any picklable Python object

```
point-to-point (sends, receives)

collective (broadcasts, scatters, gathers)
```

An example for collective scatters,

consider a list having values 0 to 79

```
 import mpi4py
 from mpi4py import MPI
 mpi4py.rc.initialize = True

 comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
 size = comm.Get_size() 
 rank = comm.Get_rank()



def processParallel(unitList):
    subList=[i**2 for i in unitList]
    return subList


if comm.rank == 0:
    #Read the data in to a list
    elementList=list(range(80))
    #divide the data in do different chunks [small groups]
    mainList = [elementList[x:x+10] for x in range(0, len(elementList), 10)]
else:
    mainList = None

unitList = comm.scatter(mainList, root=0)

comm.Barrier()
processedResult=processParallel(unitList)

# Gathering the results back to Rank 0
final_detected_data = comm.gather(processedResult, root=0)


if comm.rank == 0:
    print(final_detected_data)
```

Run the code as : python -n  python  eg : python -n 8 python sample.py

Compare the time taken to process the entire list